# Whenever gem error - Could not find command "bin/rails"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, bundler, whenever

I am trying to run a db backup every 3 hours with whenever.
The problem is that instead of running I get the following message in the cron logs:

Could not find command "bin/rails".

My schedule.rb file is simple:

```
set :bundle_command, "/usr/local/bin/bundle"

set :output, { error: '/usr/src/app/log/error.log', standard: '/usr/src/app/log/cron.log' }

require '/usr/src/app/lib/database_backup.rb'

every 2.minutes do

  runner "take_database_backup"

end
```

Rails runs inside a Docker container.

Any idea what might cause this?

Comment: If it is ok if just run the script in container's bash?

Answer (score 0):

Your `schedule.rb` specifies [`:bundle_command`](https://github.com/javan/whenever/search?q=bundle_command&unscoped_q=bundle_command), so it appears you intend the cronjob to run something using `/usr/local/bin/bundle exec ...`.

However, `:bundle_command` is only applicable to `job_type :rake` or `job_type :script`.  The [`job_type :runner`](https://github.com/javan/whenever#define-your-own-job-types) resolves to something like:

```
"cd :path && bin/rails runner -e :environment ':task' :output"
```

Note the above uses `bin/rails`, not `bundle`.  So chances are, your `bin/rails` binstub is somehow missing from wherever your `:path` resolves to.  By default the `:path` resolves to the directory in which `whenever` was executed.